# presentModalViewController horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I make the modal view controller be presented horizontally instead of vertically.

Current code:

```
ListSelectViewController *nextScreen = [[ListSelectViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nextScreen animated:YES];
[nextScreen release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only options available with `presentModalViewController:animated:` are:

- `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical` (default)
- `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`
- `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve`
- `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`

Since you're using a `navigationController`, perhaps what you want to do instead is:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextScreen animated:YES];
```

Comment: what if you're not using navigationController?

Comment: @SeungUnHam: Suggest you ask a new question but my suggestion is use a navigation controller and set its navigationBarHidden property to YES if you don't want to show the nav bar but still be able to do a push.